# Flask CLI executable not installed where I expect it in Python 3

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I'm on an Ubuntu 18.04 machine and I've got Python versions 2.7 and 3.6 installed. I first installed flask in python 2.7:

```
$ sudo pip install flask
$ flask --version
Flask 1.0.2
Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:31:15) 
[GCC 7.3.0]
```

But since I want to build my application in Python3 I uninstalled flask from python 2.7 and installed it in python 3.6:

```
$ sudo pip uninstall flask
$ sudo pip3 install flask
$ flask --version
bash: /usr/local/bin/flask: No such file or directory
```

even though it seems to be installed correctly:

```
$ python3
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import flask
>>> flask.__version__
'1.0.2'
```

Any idea how I can use the flask cli in Python 3?

p.s.: I know I can use a virtualenv, but I wonder why this happens.

[EDIT]

Ok, so I now see that flask in Python 3 is installed in my user directory:

```
>>> import flask; print(flask)
<module 'flask' from '/home/kramer65/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/__init__.py'>
```

where if I install flask in Python 2.7 it is installed globally:

```
>>> import flask; print(flask)
<module 'flask' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/__init__.pyc'>
```

Why this difference? Does anybody know how I can install flask globally in Python 3 as well?

[EDIT2]

As an answer to the question by @hoefling :

```
$ pip3 --version
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.6)
```

[EDIT3]

Turns out all of them are installed in my `~/.local/` folder. When I uninstall and then reinstall flask again, I get this (note the location paths of the other libs as well):

```
$ sudo pip3 install flask
The directory '/home/kramer65/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/kramer65/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting flask
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7f/e7/08578774ed4536d3242b14dacb4696386634607af824ea997202cd0edb4b/Flask-1.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (91kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 1.6MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.14 in /home/kramer65/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from flask)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in /home/kramer65/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from flask)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10 in /home/kramer65/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from flask)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in /home/kramer65/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from flask)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in /home/kramer65/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.10->flask)
Installing collected packages: flask
Successfully installed flask-1.0.2
```

But when I do a `pip3 show flask`, it says the location is `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages`:

```
$ pip3 show flask
Name: Flask
Version: 1.0.2
Summary: A simple framework for building complex web applications.
Home-page: https://www.palletsprojects.com/p/flask/
Author: Armin Ronacher
Author-email: armin.ronacher@active-4.com
License: BSD
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
Requires: Werkzeug, Jinja2, click, itsdangerous
```

What is going on here?

Comment: Try reinitializing your shell- `exec -l $SHELL`

Comment: What does `type -a flask` show?

Comment: @jwodder - if flask is only installed in Python 3 (and not in Python 2) then the command `type -a flask` gives me `bash: type: flask: not found`. Any idea?

Comment: I would also suggest you learn what a virtualenv is and use it... it would definitely help out with the confusion here.

Comment: @EmmEff - I know about virtualenv and I use it a lot, but I wonder why this happens. I'll clarify it in the question though.

Comment: @EmmEff Virtualenv won't help with something symlinked into `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: Where does the `pip3` command come from? Is it `python3-pip` package? What does `pip3 --version` return? Something is stale about this, when you're issuing `sudo pip3 install`, it shouldn't install in your user site (I suspect you've installed pip3.6 in user base and that it has borked ownership now since you used `sudo`).

Comment: @hoefling - The result of  `pip3 --version` is  `pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.6)`. I also added it to the question. Any idea?

Comment: Looks like you've installed flask via `pip3 install flask --user` before, this is why all the dependencies are in the user site now. Then you uninstall flask and reinstalled it via `sudo pip3 install flask` and it landed under `/usr/local/lib` as expected. Looks to me that pip works just fine, you just messed the commands up.

Comment: If you want flask and deps under `/usr/local/lib`, uninstall the deps from user site first and reinstall flask via `sudo pip3 install`; if you want it in user base, reinstall flask via `pip3 install --user flask` and precede `$HOME/.local/bin` in `PATH` so the correct flask executable is selected.